# Matlab ODE Solvers Providing Incorrect Solutions

Tags: matlab, ode

I am having a huge headache dealing with Matlab's ode solvers. Very few (If any at all) want to help me on the Matlab forums because it has been a persistent issue that I have found no solution to in the last 4 months and there is no error message to provide. Essentially, I simply want to solve the Lorentz Force differential equations using one of Matlab's ode solvers. What is so strange however, is that the ode solvers do not throw any error at me even though the solutions they provide me are wrong. I know based on my initial conditions, what a specific solution should look like. Either that, OR the solver completely ignores half the equation (Again without throwing an error) and simply solves the other half as if it's the only thing there. It is so odd and because there is no error message it has been so difficult to figure out.

Here are the files from y system in which the script does not run on my end:

"diffiqtest.m"

```
v0 = [0 0 0];
p0 = [0 0 0];
s0 = [v0 p0];
tspan = [0 5];

[t,S] = ode15s(@reffun,tspan,s0);
```

"reffun.m"

```
function refsolve = reffun(t,s)

Ex = 0;
Ey = 0;
Ez = 0;

persistent Bx By Bz
%Used so that the B-field function is only run once
if isempty(Bx)
    [Bx, By, Bz] = B_test();
end

%Reference: s(1) = vx, s(2) = vy, s(3) = vz, s(4) = x, s(5) = y, s(6) = z
ode1 = Ex + s(2).*Bz(s(4),s(5),s(6)) - s(3).*By(s(4),s(5),s(6));
ode2 = Ey + s(3).*Bx(s(4),s(5),s(6)) - s(1).*Bz(s(4),s(5),s(6));
ode3 = Ez + s(1).*By(s(4),s(5),s(6)) - s(2).*Bx(s(4),s(5),s(6));
ode4 = s(1);
ode5 = s(2);
ode6 = s(3);

refsolve = [ode1; ode2; ode3; ode4; ode5; ode6];

end
```

"B_test.m"

```
function [Bx, By, Bz] = B_test()

%Bfieldstrength = 0.64; %In (Teslas)
Bfieldstrength = 0;
magvol = 3.218E-6; %In (m)
mu0 = (4*pi)*10^-7;
magnetization = (Bfieldstrength*magvol)/mu0;

syms x y z
m = [0,0,magnetization];
r = [x, y, z];
B = mu0*(((dot(m,r)*r*3)/norm(r)^5) - m/norm(r)^3);
Bx = matlabFunction(B(1),'vars',r);
By = matlabFunction(B(2),'vars',r);
Bz = matlabFunction(B(3),'vars',r);

end
```

Initially I was getting the error:

```
Error using symengine>@()0.0
Too many input arguments.
Error in reffun (line 14)
ode1 = Ex + s(2).*Bz(s(4),s(5),s(6)) - s(3).*By(s(4),s(5),s(6));
Error in odearguments (line 90)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.
Error in ode15s (line 150)
    odearguments(FcnHandlesUsed, solver_name, ode, tspan, y0, options, varargin);
Error in diffiqtest (line 7)
[t,S] = ode15s(@reffun,tspan,s0);
```

However, on the Matlab forums someone recommended that I added another input "vars,r" when calling a matlabFunction. Another oddity here is that even though I applied this (and cleared all persistent variables), the code still did not run at all. I told him this, so he provided me his code and it worked just fine even though the exact same lines are typed out. Using his files I attempted to input initial conditions given that I knew what the solutions should look like, but they were incorrect. Again, his code was EXACTLY the same as mine, copied and pasted and it just happened to work.

This issue occurs in some much longer code I have been working on, however I decided to go back to the simplest form I could to reproduce the issue so that others may not be dissuaded from providing assistance. I am really at a stand still so any constructive advice is appreciated.

Comment: What solution were you expecting? From the current code, all fields and forces are zero, so you should get a solution that stays at the origin. // Why are you using symbolic expressions to generate a much more inefficient numeric function? You could just take the code throwing out the symbolic declarations and directly evaluate the field.

Comment: That was an error prior to posting. Comment out the assignment "Bfieldstrength = 0;" and un-comment "Bfieldstrength = 0.64;". The issue is the same nonetheless. In regards to the symbolic expression, I did that so that the differential equations can reference the local E and B fields at every time step.

Comment: Ok to the first. Still, could you explain exactly what is wrong, perhaps give a test condition for the (partial) correctness of a numerical solution? And to the second, you can achieve the same with a function call to a purely numerical evaluation of the field equations, there is no need for a symbolic pre-processing (such as deriving the dynamical equations from a Hamiltonian).

Comment: Yes, a condition I have used is as follows:

vperp = -1.3414e+12;
v0 = [vperp/2 vperp/2 0];
p0 = [0.05 0 0];
s0 = [v0 p0];
tspan = [0 10];

Where "vperp" is the perpendicular component of the initial velocity of the electron which is then split into the x and y hat components.The z hat component stays zero so that what should occur is the particle should oscillate in circles in the equatorial plane and around the entire magnet due to a magnetic field gradient affect.

Comment: I know the radius (gyro-radius) of the circles the electron will oscillate at will be 1 cm and that the radius of the orbit around the origin will be 5 cm given these initial conditions.

Comment: I am also not sure how to go about the other method you described because from what I understand, the equations need to be symbolic themselves in order to be solved and since the reference functions are a subset of them I thought those must be also.

Comment: Are you sure about that "which is then split into the x and y hat components" using division by 2? Or should it be `cos(45°)*vperp, sin(45°)*vperp` so that it has the correct Euclidean length?

Comment: I am fairly certain that just splitting the magnitude of the velocity into two different components is the correct way. Even if I did try it by dividing by sqrt(2) I still get a straight line.

Comment: It is not unexpected that a particle with a great velocity moves in a straight line. You could discuss the derivation of the exact circular solution on the physics or mathematics stackexchange forum.